# Change input value by javascript in bookmark

Tags: javascript, input, bookmarks

I need to make a bookmark which executes a javascript that changes an input value.

```
<input type="text" placeholder=" - " value=" - " class="test"/>
```

I tried several different script including this one:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document,e=d.getElementsByClassName("test");e.value="new value";})();
```

But none of them works. Can anyone help please?

Comment: `e[0].value="new value";` or `d.querySelector('.test').value="new value";`

Answer (score 0):

[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an *array-like object of all child elements with that class*. Thus, you need to select the first index of the array. This would work:

```
e=d.getElementsByClassName("test")[0]; // select first element, now e is a DOM element
```

```js
var d = document,
    e = d.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
e.value="new value";
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder=" - " value=" - " class="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object of
>   all child elements which have all of the given class names

see bellow a working snippet

```js
function myBookmark(){
  var d=document,elements=d.getElementsByClassName("test");
  for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
  elements[i].value="new value";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder=" - " value=" - " class="test"/>
<input type="text" placeholder=" - " value=" - " class="test"/>
<input type="text" placeholder=" - " value=" - " class="test"/>

<a href="javascript:myBookmark()">Execute Bookmark</a>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more versatile. Enter a selector and some text:

```
let p=prompt,
    sel=p('enter selector'),
    v=p('new value');
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel)).forEach(e=>e.value=v)
```

Passed through a bookmarklet creator:

```
javascript:(function()%7Blet%20p%3Dprompt%2Csel%3Dp('enter%20selector')%2Cv%3Dp('new%20value')%3BArray.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel)).forEach(e%3D%3Ee.value%3Dv)%7D)()
```